# How to make the 3D Cutout style. (3d paper cut)?

Tags: objects, freestyle, lineart

I found a video from “Cutout 102 - How to stylize an animation with the 3D Cutout style”
it's look cool, That's what I want to accomplish for style. I want to make it in a blender, but it is different from the video. Does anybody know how to create it? Here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrbPOeOdF0E Make sure you add an explanation to help me better understand the picture/gif.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So if you have a tutorial that explains how to do, why don't you follow his advices?

Comment: Because that video is Maya Autodesk is different from a blender, it is not the same.

Comment: More importantly, it's a tutorial/documentation for [MNPRX render engine](https://artineering.io/software/MNPRX/) specifically designed for making traditional medium looking renders, so unless that render engine exists for Blender, don't expect to be able to do such renders using the same procedures at all. That would require to to everything from scratch.